# Styling through JavaScript only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im sure there is some underlying logic here i do not understand but cannot find a solution online. Sometimes the styles are applied, sometimes they are not despite no changes being made. When i comment out a style for one ID, another ID starts working yet they are completely independent of each other, and switching ones position in the Javascript document flow makes anothers work? Only afew days into Javascript and this is very very strange to me. I am using live server on VS code.

```
const result = document.querySelector("#myElement");
result.style.color = "blue";
result.style.backgroundColor = "black";
result.style.fontSize = "80px";
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.style.color = "red";
let para = document.getElementById("p");
para.style.backgroundColor = "black";
para.style.color = "green";
```

here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="myElement">this is a heading</h1>
    <p id="p">this is a pragraph, thanks</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items-1 item">item 1</div>
      <div class="items-2 item">item 2</div>
      <div class="items-3 item">item 3</div>
      <div class="items-4 item">item 4</div>
      <div class="items-5 item">item 5</div>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">click me</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a css code override your code you can find with chrome tolls, or you can add !important tag

Comment: CSS file is empty, I understand I could use an !important tag but Im trying to understand the logic behind the styles being applied sometimes

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ probably not, since JavaScript injects the styles directly inside the element inlined, so I don't see what could override this, *unless* like you suggest, there is *another* programmatic injection *after*.

Comment: Ok with your revision, `button` is not an ID. The ID in question is `btn`.

Comment: I added the html code to the post where you can see my use of IDs

Comment: I am concerned that this was all a mistake and i didnt read my code properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to call elements by their ID, tags by their TagName, etc. see below comments and corrected code.

```
const result = document.getElementById("#myElement"); // you get an element by it's ID //
result.style.color = "blue";
result.style.backgroundColor = "black";
result.style.fontSize = "80px";
let button = document.getElementByTagName("button"); // you get a tag by it's TagName //
button.style.color = "red";
let para = document.getElementByTagName("p"); // you get a tag by it's TagName //
para.style.backgroundColor = "black";
para.style.color = "green";
```

Comment: is 'button' not the tagname for the button element? same with the p element? and 'myElement' is the id i gave it in html

Comment: Yes, but you were using `getElementById` for tags (`button` and `p`). The code I suggest corrects that like shown. I don't understand your question.

Comment: yep i had afew small brain moments for sure, looked over it so many times i should have taken a break first then looked over it before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that **one ID should be occupied only by one HTML element**. It's unique, otherwise it would be messed when you do the `getElementById`. If you want to refer to a specific element, you can use `querySelector` for single element and `querySelectorAll` for multiple element by using the respective selectors:

1. `#` for referring an element by Id.
2. `.` for referring an element by Class.
3. Just straight by the name for referring an element by the HTML tag.

For example:

```js
// Set all divs to have 300x150 and the border
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(e => {
  e.style.width = '300px';
  e.style.height = '150px';
  e.style.border = '1px solid #000';
});

// Set style specifically for one element
document.querySelector('#div_1').style.background = '#e8e8e8';

// Making all elements with class elem to have font family: serif
document.querySelectorAll('.elem').forEach(e => {
  e.style.fontFamily = 'serif';
});
```

```html
<p class="elem">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<div class="elem" id="div_1">This is div 1</div>
<div class="elem" id="div_2">This is div 2</div>
```

P.S. Just pay attention that the `querySelectorAll` shouldn't be used for referring multiple elements.